# Matlab imwrite changed my colour

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gif, colormap

I'm trying to convert some similar images from gif to png.
You can find two of the pictures here:
https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/history/1980-1989_en.
After converting the first gif (for the year 1981), you can see the background colour is the same as before, white, but for the second gif (for the year 1986), the background colour changed to pink. How to fix it?

Below is my code:

```
file_in = uigetfile('*.*', 'All Files', 'MultiSelect','on');
file_out = cellfun(@(x) cat(2, x(1:(length(x)-3)), 'png'),...
   file_in, 'UniformOutput', false); 

for i = 1: length(file_in)    
   [gif,map] = imread (file_in{i});
   imwrite (gif, map, file_out{i}, 'Background', [0 0 0]);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Matlab have never change the image color after conversion. Thus, if you try to open the 'gif' or 'png' by `imshow` you will get the same result.

[image]

Whatever, if you want to change the background color to white use [this code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/231831-changing-all-of-one-color-in-an-image-to-another#answer_187761).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm confused. Why the background is white if you view the picture using Firefox or Windows Photo Gallery?

Comment: it based on how the software interprets the color value.